# How to apply filter for newly added record in ext.js grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

In ext.js grid, I am creating a filter, after that I am dynamically adding new record in grid. Filter is not working for newly added record.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/me_astr/x87csw5a/69/) (wait for few seconds to load)

   ```
   Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/examples/ux');
   Ext.require('Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature');
   Ext.onReady(function() {

   var gstore = {
       fields: ['a', 'b', 'c']
       ,autoLoad: true
       ,proxy: {
           type: 'memory'
           ,reader: 'array'
           ,data: [
               ['Foo', 1, 'Bar']
               ,['Bar', 2, 'Baz']
               ,['Baz', 1, 'Bar']
               ,['Bat', 2, 'Baz']
           ]
       }
   };

   Ext.widget('grid', {
       renderTo: Ext.getBody()

       ,height: 400

       ,features: [{
           ftype: 'filters'
           ,local: true
       }]

       ,columns: [{
           dataIndex: 'a'
           ,text: 'Column A'
           ,filter: {
               type: 'list'
               ,options: ['Foo', 'Bar']
           }
       },{
           dataIndex: 'b'
           ,text: 'Column B'
       },{
           dataIndex: 'c'
           ,text: 'Column C',
           filter: {
               // required configs
               type: 'string',
               // optional configs
               value: '',  // setting a value makes the filter active.
               itemDefaults: {
                   // any Ext.form.field.Text configs accepted
               }
           }
       }]

       ,store: gstore

       ,tbar: [
         {
             text: 'Add new row'
             ,handler: function() {
                 var grid = this.up('grid');            
                 var newRecord = {'a': 'some', 'b': 'thing', 'c': 'else'};
                 console.log(grid.getStore());
                 grid.getStore().insert(0, newRecord);
             }
         }
       ]
   });
   }); // onReady
   ```
2. Hover mouse over column "Column C".
3. Click on drop down that
   appeared next to column, go to filters and type "Test" and then
   press enter.
4. No record will be displayed. Now click on "Add new
   row" button, it will add a new record and the record will be displayed
   even if filter condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new record, filters wont be applicable for it unless you reapply them. You can reload the filters in order to apply it on newly added record after inserting it into the store.

```
handler: function() {
   var grid = this.up('grid');            
   var newRecord = {'a': 'some', 'b': 'thing', 'c': 'else'};
   console.log(grid.getStore());
   grid.getStore().insert(0, newRecord);
   grid.filters.reload(); //Reloading the grid filters
}
```